# Remove file symbolically linked to itself?

Tags: unix, file-io

I accidentally typed this:

```
ln -s /labs/Semantic_Cognition/tp_nifti_working/masks/ b38* .
```

See that space that snuck in there, before the b38* ?  I seem to have created a file that is a symbolic link to itself:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 shanus anderson  4 2014-01-01 23:34 b38* -> b38*
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get rid of the thing.  Help?

EDIT:

Oh wait, I just realized that the asterisk was actually part of the filename.  Oops.

Comment: I reproduced the problem on my machine (you can do this with just `ln -s foo foo`) and `rm` happily removed the bogus symlink. So I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you show us what you tried to do and what errors it produced?

Comment: Hey Tim -- in the course of trying my various rm permutations so I could copy the errors I realized the issue was that the asterisk was part of the filename; when I did: "rm b38\\*" it took care of it.  (Thankfully I was at least sharp enough to escape the asterisk.)  Thanks for the prod.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem even when I did `ln -s b38\* b38\*` so I was really puzzled. But I'm glad you got it. :-)